# Android BluetoothAdapter Mocking

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to mock test Bluetooth application but my first step of creating a mock object of BluetoothAdapter class is not working!!

I'm using powermockito with easy mock.

```
 mBluetoothAdapter = (BluetoothAdapter)PowerMock.createMock(BluetoothAdapter.class);
```

this fails. with the following stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
at org.easymock.internal.DefaultClassInstantiator.getConstructorToUse(DefaultClassInstantiator.java:94)
at org.easymock.internal.AndroidClassProxyFactory.createProxy(AndroidClassProxyFactory.java:48)
at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:114)
at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:88)
at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:79)
at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.doCreateMock(PowerMock.java:2212)
at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.doMock(PowerMock.java:2163)
at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.createMock(PowerMock.java:89)
at com.xxx.blesimplesample.test.MainActivityTest.setUp(MainActivityTest.java:59)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1710)
```

Any one has used any mocking framework for Bluetooth app mocking? Any suggestions will be v helpful

Answer (score 2):

`BluetoothAdapter` in the Android framework is declared `final`, so at the time you asked this question, it couldn't be mocked, neither with Mockito nor using Robolectric.

However, Android unit testing has changed a lot since then. With recent versions of the tools, when you build unit tests the tools generate a patched `android.jar` with all the `final`s removed. This makes all Android classes available for mocking. Nowadays, if you want to mock any Bluetooth code, you can do so in the standard way. The code you've already tried will "just work" if you update to the latest tools. Alternatively, Robolectric has a `ShadowBluetoothAdapter` class built in now.